# Java Object Ordering for Sorted Collections

Tags: java, collections, treeset

When I'm looking at the [Java Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) tutorial, the last section **'Comparators'** of the article confused me a little bit.

By defining a class `Employee` which itself is comparable by employee's name, the tutorial doesn't show if this class has overridden the `equals` method. Then it uses a customized [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in which the employees are sorted by the seniority to sort a list of employees and which I could understand.

Then the tutorial explains why this won't work for a sorted collection such as [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)), and the reason is:

> it generates an ordering that is not compatible with equals. This means that this Comparator equates objects that the equals method does not. In particular, any two employees who were hired on the same date will compare as equal. When you're sorting a List, this doesn't matter; but when you're using the Comparator to order a sorted collection, it's fatal. If you use this Comparator to insert multiple employees hired on the same date into a TreeSet, only the first one will be added to the set; the second will be seen as a duplicate element and will be ignored.

Now I'm confused, since I know `List` allows duplicate elements while [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't based on `equals` method. So I wonder when the tutorial says the ordering generated by the `Comparator` is not compatible with equals, what does it mean? And it also says 'If you use this Comparator to insert multiple employees hired on the same date into a TreeSet, only the first one will be added to the set; the second will be seen as a duplicate element and will be ignored.' I don't understand how using a `Comparator` will affect the use of original `equals` method. I think my question is how the `TreeSet` will be produced and sorted in this case and when the `compare` and `equals` methods are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I wonder when the tutorial says the ordering generated by the Comparator is not compatible with equals, what does it mean?

In this example, the `Comparator` compares two `Employee` objects based on their seniority alone. This comparison does not in any way use `equals` or `hashCode`. Keeping that in mind, when we pass this `Comparator` to a `TreeSet`, the set will consider any result of 0 from the `Comparator` as equality. Therefore, if any `Employee`s share starting dates, only one will be added because the set thinks they are equal.

Finally:

> I think my question is how the TreeSet will be produced and sorted in this case and when the compare and equals methods are used.

For the `TreeSet`, if a `Comparator` is given, it uses the `compare` method to determine equality and ordering of objects. If no `Comparator` is given, then the set uses the `compareTo` method of the objects being sorted (they must implement `Comparable`).

The reason why the Java specification claims that the `compare`/`compareTo` method being used must be in line with `equals` is because the `Set` specification makes use of `equals`, even though this specific type of `Set`, the `TreeSet`, uses comparisons instead.

If you ever receive a `Set` from some method implementation, you can expect that there are no duplicates of the objects in that `Set` as defined by the `equals` method. Because `TreeSet` doesn't use this method, however, developers must be careful to ensure that the comparison method results in the same equality as `equals` does.

Comment: Thanks! And now I understand this is to keep it consistent with the `Set` interface and I saw methods like `contains()` which use `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

A `TreeSet` uses only the Comparator to determine if two elements are "equal":

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. *The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.*

This means that the Comparator should return 0 if and only if the `equals` returns true, to get a consistent behaviour between TreeSet and other sets, like a `HashSet`. The `HashSet` indeed uses `equals` and the hash code to determine if two elements are "equal".

Comment: I didn't quite get your answer until Zircon elaborated on it. Still, thank you so much.