# Java TreeSet not adding object

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I am trying to add objects into a Treeset but the objects not all are getting added.

```
class Fruits
{
     String name ;
     int weight;
     int price;

    Fruits(String n, int w, int p)
    { 
        this.name=n;
        this.weight=w;
        this.price =p;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("hashcode called");
        int prime =31;
        int result =1;
        result = prime*result +(this.name.hashCode()+this.price+this.weight);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Equals called");
        if(null!=obj)
        {
            Fruits f= (Fruits) obj;
            if(this.name.equals(f.name) && this.price==f.price && this.weight == f.price)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class FruitsComparator implements Comparator<Fruits>
{
    //Order by Name, then quanity and then Price
    @Override
    public int compare(Fruits f1, Fruits f2)
    {
        if(f1.name.equals(f2.name) && f1.weight == f2.weight && f1.price == f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(1);
            return 0;
        }
        else if(f1.name.equals(f2.name) && f1.weight==f2.weight && f1.price < f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(2);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (f1.name.equals(f2.name) && f1.weight==f2.weight && f1.price > f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(3);
            return 1;
        }
        else if (f1.name.equals(f2.name) && f1.weight<f2.weight && f1.price == f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(4);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (f1.name.equals(f2.name) && f1.weight>f2.weight && f1.price == f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(5);
            return 1;
        }
        else if (f1.name.compareTo(f2.name) <1 && f1.weight==f2.weight && f1.price == f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(6);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (f1.name.compareTo(f2.name) >1 && f1.weight==f2.weight && f1.price == f2.price)
        {
            System.out.println(7);
            return 1;
        }
            return 0;
    }       
}
```

From public static void main of another class.

```
Fruits f1= new Fruits("Apple",1,3);
Fruits f2= new Fruits("Apple",10,1);
Fruits f3= new Fruits("Apple",15,2);
Set<Fruits> sf = new TreeSet<Fruits>(new FruitsComparator());
sf.add(f1);
sf.add(f2);
sf.add(f3);
System.out.println("--Fruits Example--");
for( Fruits f: sf)
{
    System.out.println(f.name+"-"+f.weight+"-"+f.price);
}
```

The output I get is :

```
--Fruits Example--
Apple-1-3
```

But when I have fruits objs as below i get the all the objects
just keeping everything same but the third element.
     Fruits f1= new Fruits("Apple",1,3);
        Fruits f2= new Fruits("Apple",1,1);
        Fruits f3= new Fruits("Apple",1,2);

The output get for this is

```
--Fruits Example--
Apple-1-1
Apple-1-2
Apple-1-3
```

So somehow my objects are treated as same when I keep different elements on weight and price. I couldn't figure out as why the objects are treated as same. Please help.

Comment: Voting to close as a copy-paste error (`f.price` should be `f.weight`).

Comment: Your comparator implementation is so confusing as to be unreadable, let alone fixable.  Also, `.compareTo` results should be compared to 0, not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is, you are always checking two fields to be equal and only one to be different.
At the final else, that happens if at least 2 fields are different, you return 0 which means they should be treated as equal, and that is the reason you have this issue.

Since the order you want is to first sort by name, then by quantity and then by price, remove the  `&& f1.price == f2.price` from the 4th condition onwards, and remove `&& f1.weight==f2.weight` on the last two.

---

You can avoid this issue completely if you use Java 8 style.

```
Set<Fruits> sf = new TreeSet<Fruits>(Comparator.comparing(Fruits::getName)
    .thenComparing(Fruits::getWeight)
    .thenComparing(Fruits::getPrice)
    );
```

---

I have added the working code in [codiva - online java compiler ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/1d295c6d-3dbd-4ea8-8110-c89858e476a2). I have also included a slightly cleaner implementation in FruitsComparator.java file.

Answer (score 1):

**Tree related collections don't use `equals()` or `hashCode()`. Those come into play for `Map`.**

Your conditions in the `compare` result in a `0`, hence the fruit isn't inserted.

First Apple goes in as the tree is empty. The 2nd & 3rd Apple result in `false` in all the `if` conditions, thus returning the final `0`. Put a `System.out.println()` before the final `return` to confirm.

If you want to sort the fruits first by name, then by weight & then finally by price, here's a more compact way doing it:

```
@Override
public int compare(Fruits f1, Fruits f2) {
    if (f1.name.equals(f2.name)) {
        if (f1.weight < f2.weight) {
            return -1;
        } else if (f1.weight > f2.weight) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (f1.price < f2.price) {
                return -1;
            } else if (f1.price > f2.price) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return f1.name.compareTo(f2.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe thats where the problem lies. But i don't understand why the conditions are met in my compare method. Please take a look if you find some time. Thanks.

Comment: None of your conditions are met. Place a `System.out.println(8)` after the 7th one, after the complete `if` block to view this. In every `if` condition, you have at least one of either `name`,`weight` or `price` being equal/`==`, whereas none of the three apples have the same `weight` or `price`.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet`, when used with a `Comparator`, the elements' equality is decided by the `compare` method of the `Comparator`, otherwise would use the `compareTo` method of its element since they are required to implement the `Comparable` interface. The `hashcode` and `equals` methods will only be used by the `Set` interface itself (such as method `contains` uses `equals` method to check if the elements are presented). And `hashcode` is not something that a `TreeSet` to use while it is used by `HashSet` which is totally another way to implement `Set` interface. Thus, in your code, since the `compare` method you've overridden of the `Comparator` treats these elements equal, so they cannot be inserted for multiple times. One guideline that the Java Tutorial points out is, the `compare` method should comply with the `equals` methods, which is, the elements should be treated equal in the `compare` method if and only if the `equals` method do.

And in your `equals` method, you did use `this.weight == f.price` to compare two fruits, which I don't think is what you intended to do. This makes your `equals` methods not consistent with the `compare` method.

For your reference, see [Java Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) tutorial, and as well as [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37925531/6041964) I asked two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `equals` method in class `Fruits`:

```
if(this.name.equals(f.name) && this.price==f.price && this.weight == f.price)
```

should have been:

```
if(this.name.equals(f.name) && this.price==f.price && this.weight == f.weight)
```

(note the last part).

Comment: I changed the typo but still the behavior doesnt change. I believe I need to re look my compare in the comparator class. Thanks.

Comment: TreeSet and TreeMap does not use equals and hashCode methods anyway. They will be used for HashSet and HashMap. For this question, they are irrelevant. 
Look at my answer for the correct fix. The fix is in the comparator.